# Negate a $regex for mongodb in Yii2

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I use $regex inside an aggregation pipeline $match instruction in PHP. I need to find a record that "does not contain" a certain string. I'v found out online that $not operator is used for such cases, but if I try to do so like this:

```
$regex = "/.*".$sometext.".*";    
$use['$not'] = $regex;
```

also this one does not work:

```
new \MongoRegex("/.*".$sometext.".*")
$use['$not'] = $regex;
```

In short I need to find  a text that does not contain a certain string

Comment: What about it 'does not work'? Please be more specific.

Comment: What are using this with i.e. `find()->where(~)`?

Comment: it says exception: invalid use of $not, json_ecoded query looks like this {"$match":{"value.userData.name":{"$not":"\/.*master.*\/"}}}

Comment: The first query won't work as `$in` requires either document or regex object.For the second query your [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php#mongoregex.intro) is wrong. try `$use[$not'] = new MongoRegex("/.*".$sometext.".*/")` .